# scientific notation displayed as decimal in table

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I am currently filling an HTML table with JSON data I get from my server.

the JSON looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "field1":"someString",
      "value":6e-21
   },
   {
      "field1":"someOtherString",
      "value":1e-4
   }
]
```

But in the HTML table, the "value" field get sometimes converted to decimal notation if the number fit in the div

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e27w2poa/3/) demonstrating the issue

I would like to have all values in scientific notation in the HTML table (like in my JSON data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `toExponential()` function as follows:

```
data[result].value.toExponential()
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential):

> The `toExponential()` method returns a string representing the `Number`
>   object in exponential notation.

Here's a complete snippet:

```js
var data = [{
  "field1": "someString",
  "value": 6e-21
}, {
  "field1": "someOtherString",
  "value": 1e-4
}];

var htmlContent = "<tbody>";

for (let result in data) {
  htmlContent += "<tr><td>" + data[result].field1 + "</td><td>" + data[result].value.toExponential() + "</td></tr>";
}

document.getElementById('table').innerHTML += htmlContent + "</tbody>";
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>generated from JSON:  </p>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>field1</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<p>expected:</p>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>field1</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>someString</td>
      <td>6e-21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>someOtherString</td>
      <td>1e-4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert all values to string

```
var data = [{
  "field1": "someString",
    "value": "6e-21"
}, {
   "field1": "someOtherString",
    "value": "1e-4"
```

}];

Working fiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/e27w2poa/4/

Comment: Forgot to say that I need be able to sort the data in the table, so I need to keep them as double. Thanks anyway for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toExponential()` to convert back into exponential form. Working JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e27w2poa/5/